# Xamarin forms, What do i need to do in IOS projects so the photo will show up in IOS emulator?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]The Android emulator is showing the photo but when i try the IOS emulator the photo doesn't show up.  The photo is in resources and it's property is Embedded Resource.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images

Comment: i can't access IOS designer??

Comment: Did the photo show up in iOS simulator successfully?

Comment: yes..on each property of image.... android - select android resource on property then on ios make file bundle resource..

Answer (score 0):

From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images), it says:

> Prior to iOS 9, images were typically placed in the Resources folder
>   with Build Action: BundleResource. However, this method of working
>   with images in an iOS app has been deprecated by Apple.

I just did a test on iOS and found if you put the photo in resources, it still work. The right way is:

If you are using a `.jpg` photo, you have to write the full name(I guess you missed the `.jpg`):

```
<Image Source="logo.jpg" />
```

If you are using a `.png` photo, you can just use the photo's name:

```
<Image Source="logo" />
```

I don't recommend you to add photo in this way as it has been **deprecated** by Apple. Now, Apple recommend you **adding-images-to-the-asset-catalog-image-set**:

Go to `Assets.xcassets` -> New `A New Image Set` -> add your photos there(`1x,2x,3x`).

There are detailed steps in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=macos#adding-images-to-an-asset-catalog-image-set) that you can follow.